# Enable audio output on both HDMI and headphone

Tags: sound, hdmi, headphones

I found a lot of questions about how to *switch* between HDMI and headphone outputs.
Instead, on my Ubuntu 21.10 I need to output the audio on *both* of them.

Under `Settings` > `Sound` > `Output Device` I can select one output only per time.

Is there a way to route the audio on both HDMI and analog output?

EDIT:

Following [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143865/how-to-enable-both-built-in-audio-output-and-hdmi-audio-output-with-pulseaudio) approach, I enabled the simultaneous output on `paprefs` and installed `pavucontrol`. So I can see the virtual output of the "combined" audio sinks. Still, the audio comes from only output only.

Comment: What further details you may need to address this issue?